# How to check if custom android is rooted?

Tags: android

We've bought some custom android tablets, that we're going to use as kiosk tablets. For our kiosk app to work properly the app needs root access.

How can I check if the device is rooted properly?
And how can I root it if it isn't?

**Things that point to that the device IS rooted:**

1. When I ADB shell into the tablet the line starts with "#" (I read somewhere that this means that the tablet is rooted).
2. When I run "su" in the shell nothing happens (no errors).
3. This file exist /system/xbin/su"

**Things that point to that the device IS NOT rooted:**

1. I have installed Root Checker, it says "Sorry! This device does not
   have root access"
2. When I run the following code in our app, which I know for a fact is working on
   other rooted devices:

   ```
   Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
   os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
   os.writeBytes(cmd + "\n");
   ```

   I get an error: "java.io.IOException: write failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe)".

Comment: What's the issue?  It sounds like you solved your own question.

Comment: @DeeV my issue is that Root Checker says that there's no root access, and it causes my app to fail. But I don't understand why it isn't rooted, given the mentioned things

Answer (score 0):

Had to try a number of different root tools. Turns out KingRoot (https://kingroot.net/) did the job. Afterwards Root Checker says that it is rooted correctly and my app works again.

Answer (score 0):

There is this nice guide which you can follow to check if the phone is rooted or not.

[Link to website](http://www.wikihow.tech/Check-if-Your-Android-Cellphone-Is-Rooted-or-Not)